# How to call node.js server side method from javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to node.js but I know somewhat about socketstream web framework by using this I can easily call a server side node.js method from JavaScript. I don't know how to do this without using that framework. How can I call the node.js method from JavaScript?

The below code is using socketstream to call server side method. So I want to call the same server side method without using this framework.

```
ss.rpc('FileName.methodName',function(res){ 
    alert(res);         
});
```

Comment: Afaik (correct me if I'm wrong), you can't directly call a method on the server from a client. You can however, send some sort of request to the server with the method name attached, and then the server can invoke it.

Comment: @Supericy :thanks for your response but i don't know how to call directly.can u explain that in code.

Comment: You need to expose an endpoint for the client to request. With express.js, that might be something like `app.get('/some.name', function(req, res) { // call code })`. Then you can hit that endpoint via an AJAX call on the client.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'd suggest use [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/)

Server-side code

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80); // initiate socket.io server

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' }); // Send data to client

  // wait for the event raised by the client
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {  
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

and client-side

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost'); // connec to server
  socket.on('news', function (data) { // listen to news event raised by the server
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' }); // raise an event on the server
  });
</script>
```

**Alternatively,** you can use a router function which calls some function on specific request from the client

```
var server = connect()
    .use(function (req, res, next) {
      var query;
      var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
      query = url_parts.query;

      if (req.method == 'GET') {
        switch (url_parts.pathname) {
            case '/somepath':
            // do something
            call_some_fn()
            res.end();
            break;
          }
        }
    })
    .listen(8080);
```

And fire `AJAX` request using JQuery

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: '/somepath',
    success: function (data) {
        // use data
    }
})
```

Comment: Socket.IO may be overkill if they are not sending a large number of requests (which the OP seemed to indicate).

Comment: Agreed, alternatively he can use `connect` and a router function to call some function when client fires an `HTTP` request.

Comment: I realize that this thread is a bit dated but how about using `express`? as `var app = express();.....app.get('/dbquery',function(req,res){//do some db stuff....}); .....app.listen(2999,function(){...});` this would make a service listening on port 2999 and any call to the `/dbquery` service would return/do something based on the request.

Answer (score 1):

Not exaclty sockets but a simple solution:

Can I suggest trying [api-mount](https://www.npmjs.com/package/api-mount). It basically allows calling API as simple functions without having to think about AJAX requests, fetch, express, etc. Basically in server you do:

```
const ApiMount = apiMountFactory()
ApiMount.exposeApi(api)
```

"api" is basically an object of methods/functions that you are willing to call from your web application.

On the web application you then do this:

```
const api = mountApi({baseUrl: 'http://your-server.com:3000'})
```

Having done that you can call your API simply like this:

```
const result = await api.yourApiMethod()
```

Try it out. Hope it helps.

Comment: Really good solution, I wonder why nobody upvoted this answer as socket.io is definitely a overkill!

Comment: Feel free to use. I think I will need to improve documentation or make some YouTube with explanation to attract more users. It is super easy to use but I realize that docs look over-complicated :D

Comment: Yes, that would we awesome as well.
BTW: I created my own solution becoz I didn't read your answer at that time.
Check it out at: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rpc-middleware

Demo here: https://rpc-demo.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Cool! Simple lightweight solution and tbh very similar. Abstraction is maybe at a slightly different level.

api-mount abstracts away both client and server. There is one entry-point for browser and another for server even though it is only 1 package. Or alternatively someone could use api-mount-client or api-mount-server if they do not like having 2 in 1.

Comment: Yes, I am fan of your approach and library.

A good thing I implemented with my lib is that I added support for integrating it with any existing express servers. And that makes it usable by existing backend servers using expressjs.

To be honest I haven't used either of lib in any project yet but it is way too cool though. :D