# Calling apis like chargebee with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, chargebee

I'm a little be confused when it comes to calling APIs over node.js. 
I have a server running node js where I can install frameworks like the one for chargebee.

I created a html page where I make subscriptions etc. Now I would want to call the corresponding chargebee function to make the subscription. 
If I try to load chargebee with `require('chargebee')`it failes. I can only load it in the server js.

So how would it be possible for me to use the functionalities of chargebee?

Is it possible that I invoke a function from chargbee by a click on the button? Do i have to provide this function by express?

I think I did not understand the difference between client side code and server side code when it comes to node.js.
How can function on the server side be invoked by clicks on html buttons for example?

Comment: for the different between client and server side js, what ever runs @ ur browser is client side which u can find by view-source/inspect-tools of browser code. what ever runs @ command line code through server.js/what so.. is server side code..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to trigger request from client side you can use forms or AJAX. Here is an example with express framework in which form is used to trigger request and create subscription in chargebee

Client-Side Code:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <form action="/subscribe" method="post">
            <label for="name">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="customer[first_name]" placeholder="first name" />
            <br />
            <label for="name">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="customer[last_name]" placeholder="last name" />
            <br />
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="customer[email]" placeholder="Enter your email address" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Create Profile" />
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Node-Server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var chargebee = require("chargebee");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
}));

chargebee.configure({site : "<<site_name>>",
  api_key : "<<api_key>>"

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/form.html');
});

app.post('/subscribe', function(req, res){
      var params = req.body;// getting form params as JSON
      params['plan_id']='enterprise'; // plan id that is present in your Chargebee site
      chargebee.subscription.create(params).request(function(error,result){
        if(error){
          //handle error
          console.log(error);
        }else{
          console.log(result);
          var subscription = result.subscription;
          res.writeHead(200, {
             'content-type': 'text/plain'
          });
          res.write('Successfully created subscription\n\n' + 'id :: '+ subscription.id);
          res.end();
       }
     });
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("server listening on 3000");
```

Comment: Thx for the solution. So is there no way to access the chargbee functions directly? I mean is it possible to load the library with require as an external js and call the funtions?

Comment: I am not sure about the questions. Do you want to access functions directly from client side script?

Comment: Your answer is really good. I just need to understand if it is possible. Why are chargebee functions not invoked directly on user click.

Comment: It is not possible to directly call the function from client side(on click). Chargebee node library is an api wrapper to call the api from server using basic auth and cannot be used on client side. Javascript library which work directly on client are different from node js.

Comment: Thank you. Now i understand how it works. Would socket.io have any advantage?

Comment: You can refer this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951251/how-to-call-node-js-server-side-method-from-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with chargebee v3 .  Hope This will solve your query

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>chargebee Example</title>
    <script src = "https://js.chargebee.com/v2/chargebee.js"  data-cb-site = "your site name" > </script>
</head>
<body>
        <!-- for creating subscription -->
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-cb-type="checkout" data-cb-plan-id="30" >subscribe</a>
        <!-- for managing portal -->
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-cb-type="portal" >Manage account</a>
</body>
</html>
```