# Respond to client after receiving client to server POST request (Node.JS)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js

I have been attempting to respond to a client-side request with Node.JS. I have discovered [Node JS - call function on server from client javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34457415/node-js-call-function-on-server-from-client-javascript), which seems to explain what I want, except that I can't seem to translate it to my program.
Here is the request via POST in index.html:

```html
$.post("/", {data: 'hi'}, function(result){
      $("body").html(result);
    });
```

what I was hoping it would do would be write the result of the call, from my server.js (Node):

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

function handler(data, app){
    if(req.method == "POST"){ 
        app.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        app.writeHead(200);
        app.end(data);
    }
}

const BUILDPATH = path.join(__dirname);

const { PORT = 3000 } = process.env;

const app = express();
app.set('port', PORT);

app.use(express.static(BUILDPATH));
app.get('/*', (req, res) => res.sendFile('static/index.html', { root: BUILDPATH }));

const httpServer = http.createServer(app);

httpServer.listen(PORT);

console.info(` Client Running on: http://localhost:${PORT}`);
```

Comment: You haven't defined the `POST` route for `/`. Your server doesn't know how to respond to a `POST` because you haven't told it to even look for it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this code:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

function handler(data, app){
    if(req.method == "POST"){ 
        app.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        app.writeHead(200);
        app.end(data);
    }
}

const BUILDPATH = path.join(__dirname);

const { PORT = 3000 } = process.env;

const app = express();
app.set('port', PORT);

app.use(express.static(BUILDPATH)); 
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res
       // best practice is to always return an status code
       .status(200)
       // just return an json object
       .json({"msg": "ok, it all works just fine"})
});

const httpServer = http.createServer(app);

httpServer.listen(PORT);

console.info(` Client Running on: http://localhost:${PORT}`);
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is, is that the only route your Node server listens to is the one you define with `/*`. As you can see, that route returns your index.html file to the client. You did not specify a route that listens for a request that comes from the client.

To solve the issue, you will have to define a route that listens on a specific route for the request you are trying to make from your client.

I see you are using ExpressJS. [here](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req) is the documentation on writing routes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I think I actually understand some small part of Node!