# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: spawn is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, react-redux

I am bit stuck here. I am submitting an async request with redux-thunk in my action creator which looks like this:

```
export const downloadFromYoutube = (download) => {
  console.log("Hello");
    return dispatch => {
      var YoutubeMp3Downloader = require('youtube-mp3-downloader');

      var YD = new YoutubeMp3Downloader({
          "ffmpegPath": "/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.2.2/bin/ffmpeg",        // Where is the FFmpeg binary located?
          "outputPath": "/Users/dominik/Coding/youtube-downloader-papa/downloads",    // Where should the downloaded and encoded files be stored?
          "youtubeVideoQuality": "highest",       // What video quality should be used?
          "queueParallelism": 2,                  // How many parallel downloads/encodes should be started?
          "progressTimeout": 2000                 // How long should be the interval of the progress reports
      });

      console.log("Hello");
      YD.on("finished", data => dispatch({ type: "FINISHED", payload: data }));
      YD.on("error", error => dispatch({ type: "ERROR", payload: error }));
      YD.on("progress", progress => dispatch({ type: "PROGRESS", payload: progress }));

      // dispatch a "starting" action
      // dispatch({ type: "STARTING" });

      // start the download
      YD.download("UDzGLMLhy80");
     }
  };
```

But I am always getting the following error:

> TypeError: spawn is not a function

I am using React/Redux in electron. I also should mention redux-thunk does work when I use a timeout function instead of the download function. However, the code above & use of the youtube downloader library also works fine when I just put it in a plain javascript / nodejs file and execute it, so it seems to have something to do with the way I handle promises in React.

Here is the full error log:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: spawn is not a function(…)(anonymous
>   function) @ processor.js:135proto._getFfmpegPath @
>   capabilities.js:90proto._spawnFfmpeg @
>   processor.js:115proto.availableFormats.proto.getAvailableFormats @
>   capabilities.js:514(anonymous function) @ capabilities.js:564fn @
>   async.js:746(anonymous function) @ async.js:1213(anonymous function) @
>   async.js:166(anonymous function) @ async.js:706(anonymous function) @
>   async.js:167async.waterfall @ async.js:710proto._checkCapabilities @
>   capabilities.js:561(anonymous function) @ processor.js:287fn @
>   async.js:746(anonymous function) @ async.js:1213(anonymous function) @
>   async.js:166(anonymous function) @ async.js:706(anonymous function) @
>   async.js:167async.waterfall @ async.js:710proto._prepare @
>   processor.js:284proto.exec.proto.execute.proto.run @
>   processor.js:420proto.saveToFile.proto.save @ recipes.js:28(anonymous
>   function) @ YoutubeMp3Downloader.js:151emitOne @ events.js:77emit @
>   events.js:169(anonymous function) @ index.js:113emitOne @
>   events.js:77emit @ events.js:169ClientRequest._connect @
>   request.js:235(anonymous function) @ request.js:128

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spawn is a construct of nodejs. React as a framework does not have the method. This library is to be used in server side (nodejs). You can expose a http api which can be triggered via react. The http api can then trigger the library in nodejs server.

Comment: thank you so much, that explains it all. I thus need to somehow call my electron renderer process from my action creator. If you have any idea how to do this, I have submitted [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42531901/call-renderer-process-from-react-redux-action-electron) which specifies that problem further, as it does not seem relevant here since you've answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951251/how-to-call-node-js-server-side-method-from-javascript) article:

using Socket.IO

Server-side code

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80); // initiate socket.io server

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' }); // Send data to client

  // wait for the event raised by the client
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {  
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

and client-side:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost'); // connec to server
  socket.on('news', function (data) { // listen to news event raised by the server
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' }); // raise an event on the server
  });
</script>
```