# Call renderer process from React-Redux action (Electron)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, electron

I have a electron application which uses React & Redux, so I have action creators, reducers etc.

I also have a function in my renderer file (nodejs) which does some async stuff.

I want to call this function from within my action creator. I guess I will have to use redux-thunk for this or some other async library, however, I am not quite sure how to access this function in the renderer process and use it in my react.redux app?

So e.g. for the action creator:

```
export const downloadFromYoutube = (download) => {
//I want to call the function here
};
```

and my renderer file only contains this one function which does async stuff:

```
var YoutubeMp3Downloader = require('youtube-mp3-downloader');

function downloadFromYoutube() {
  console.log("Hello");
  //Configure YoutubeMp3Downloader with y our settings
  var YD = new YoutubeMp3Downloader({
      "ffmpegPath": "/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.2.2/bin/ffmpeg",        // Where is the FFmpeg binary located?
      "outputPath": "/Users/dominik/Coding/youtube-downloader-papa/downloads/",    // Where should the downloaded and encoded files be stored?
      "youtubeVideoQuality": "highest",       // What video quality should be used?
      "queueParallelism": 2,                  // How many parallel downloads/encodes should be started?
      "progressTimeout": 2000                 // How long should be the interval of the progress reports
  });
  console.log("Downloading");
  //Download video and save as MP3 file
  YD.download("jhjPSj-qnyg");


  YD.on("finished", function(data) {
      console.log(data);
  });

  YD.on("error", function(error) {
      console.log(error);
  });

  YD.on("progress", function(progress) {
      console.log(progress);
  });
}


    }
```

Comment: If you have it in a separate module, you should simply be able to require it where you define your action creator. If it uses native functionality, you need to require like this: `var downloadFromYoutube = require('electron').remote.require('./downloadFromYoutube.js')` assuming the name of your module is `downloadFromYoutube.js`.

Comment: thank you first of all. i originally put it in the renderer file electron provides. However, I have  now created a file like you suggested ('downloadFromYoutube.js‌​'), but I get `Error: Cannot find module 'electron'`

Comment: First off, just try importing it using `require('downloadFromYoutube.js‌')` (i.e. without importing electron and using remote first). If it complains, then I believe electron extends the `window` object, so perhaps you could use `const downloadFromYoutube = window.require('electron').remote.require('./downloadFromYoutube.js‌​';`.

Comment: thank you. it does not complain when I require it directly, however, it also does not work. When i change the file name to something that *does not* exist, it also does not complain however.

Comment: If I import a file with `require('../../test.js‌');` and that file contains the function , `downloadSomething()` should I then be able to just do `downloadSomething();` in my file which imports this function? I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: downloadSomething is not defined`

Comment: When you use `require()` you're importing a module - it isn't quite like just importing a file, you have to define what that module consists of, i.e. the public interface of that module. In this case you can simply add `exports.module = downloadFromYoutube` to the end of your `downloadFromYoutube.js` file and the reference error should disappear. I do recommend you read up on how modules work in JavaScript as it is very omnipresent.