# Call server side JS function from Client using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a server side javascript file `index.js`, running locally using nodejs:

```
function myFunction() {
    console.log("It works!");
}
```

I would like to call this function from client side using Ajax:

```
<body        
    <button id="mybtn" onclick="callMyFunction()">Call function</button>

    <script>
        function callMyFunction() {
            // Creating Our XMLHttpRequest object 
            var url = '/index.js';
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            // Making our connection  
            xhttp.open("GET", url, true);

            // function execute after request ist successful
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    console.log(this.responseText)
                    // What to do here?
                }
            };

            // Sending our request
            xhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

I don't know how to properly call that function?

Later this function should run on a webserver and every client should be able to call that function.

Comment: You cannot call a node function directly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call node.js server side method from javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951251/how-to-call-node-js-server-side-method-from-javascript)

Comment: @evolutionxbox what am I doing then to solve this?

Comment: Have a look at the question I linked? Try calling the function when an endpoint is accessed

Comment: Your lost treasure is called [RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call)

Comment: OR simply creat an HTTP endpoint, hit that endpoint, and boom. write whatever code you wanna do in that endpoint handler.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I don't get how to do that?